# Mac Catalina Clang not able to find header files in /usr/local/include

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

Currently I am trying to compile a llvm C++ file including the following header file:

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
```

and I have made sure that clang-c/Index.h does exist in /usr/local/include/clang-c/Index.h, but when I try to compile it with

```
clang++ main.cpp
```

the compile says

```
fatal error: 'clang-c/Platform.h' file not found
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I seem to remember /usr/local/include not being on the default include path

Comment: ... following on from previous comment... try adding `-I /usr/local/include` and `-L /usr/local/lib` to your `clang++` command.

Comment: Cool. You can add it as the answer, accept it and bag the points. Then others will see the way to solve it.